# How can I set a relative-path to compile my workspace in another machine?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have written some code for publisher and subscriber and I am currently using SVN for versioning.
I committed the entire workspace, now when I took the checkout on other machine, I am not able to compile the source code.
I get the source-directory not found error.

I know that obviously its not the same workspace but is there a workaround to update the relative path, so that the next time anyone takes any checkout, the source code compiles on their machine ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124961/how-can-i-set-a-relative-path-to-compile-my-workspace-in-another-machine-?/) by [rosAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/9296/rosas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be a little more specific about what you commit to version control.

In general, you don't want to commit any anything that can be rebuilt by the build process.

Specifically for ROS, you don't want to commit:

- The build, bin and lib directories in rosbuild packages
- Generated message files, headers, etc
- The build, devel and install directories in a catkin workspace

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have gotten the same problem with git.

The steps I recommend you is make a svn ignore global list (in git is .gitignore) and put the name of the autogenerated files in order to not commit them into your rep. In rosbuild are:

```
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeLists.txt.user
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeFiles/
build/
bin/
msg_gen/
srv_gen/
.DS_Store
.cproject
.project
.pydevproject
*~
```

---

Originally posted by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) with karma: 330 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-07**:
delete CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles folder. Everything should compile....